# Machine Learning algorithm suggestion

Tags: machine-learning

I want to experiment some new things in ML.
I used a lots GA to solve complex problem but now I want to try something new.

My problem is very simple: 
I have 3/4 objects with different size and a parcel where puts the objects. 
The goal is estimate the correct parcel content.

Now I have solved the problem using a table where store all the previous data (Knowledge ) and return the result more close with the input data. 
Formally, it works and learn from the past but is it ML?

I want that the software learn how objects can be store in the parcel.

What's the algorithm that I need?

I already solve the problem with GA.

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I bet Reinforcement Learning (RL) is what you're looking for. It wouldn't be as straight forward as GA to get started. You may have to create your own environment.

Your actions could be putting/removing object from the parcel.
You might define a reward (+ value) if the guess is correct and a negative reward if the guess is wrong. And thus train the algorithm for a number of episodes.

I suspect you could solve this problem easily with Q learning. You would rather go for Q table method rather than a DQN (Deep Q Network) considering the simplicity of the problem.

RL is best used for optimization tasks, and this problem is great just to get started. I've also solved optimization tasks with both GA and RL, but of course you do feel some "intelligence" with RL.

[This](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-reinforcement-learning-4339519de419) article gives a clear overview of RL with a worked example.

openAI [gym](https://gym.openai.com/) is a library that makes the life of RL programmer easy.

You may create a custom environment like [this](https://medium.com/@apoddar573/making-your-own-custom-environment-in-gym-c3b65ff8cdaa). And define how to assign rewards and how next state is found etc.